# jQuery Table show all rows option in Show entities drop down list

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have used JQuery table to show my items in a table. How can I add an extra option to show all items in the "Show entities" drop down list?

```
var table = $('#tblInvoices').dataTable({
        "columnDefs": [
            { "visible": false, "targets": 2 }
        ],
        "order": [[2, 'asc']],
        "displayLength": 50
});
```

Comment: post relevent code also...you are using datatable.js..???

Comment: Yes I am using jquery.datatable.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `"lengthMenu"` while configuring datatable as shown :

```
var table = $('#tblInvoices').dataTable({
     "columnDefs": [
            { "visible": false, "targets": 2 }],
     "order": [[2, 'asc']],
     "displayLength": 50,
     "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]]
});
```

[Reference.](http://www.datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/length_menu.html)

Comment: thanks Kartikeya, I will accept it as correct answer after 3 minutes. I have another question about grouping, I am going to open another thread for it.